# API Fetch per React Native - Different Terminal Log compared to Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, fetch-api

I am struggling with a request. I just want to get a cat-picture URL using this site: https://thecatapi.com/.

If I fetch the data using the browser I get the right JavaScript Object with the URL I need,
but if I try it with my code I get a promise I can't understand/ use. See the code and console log below:

```
const myHeaders = new Headers({
  'x-api-key': "MYREQUESTED-APIKEY"
});

const myRequest = new Request('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?size=full', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders
});

let catObj = fetch(myRequest)
  .then((response) => response.json())

console.log(catObj)

//Console Log:

Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

I am new to programming and struggle quite a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just await your promise

```
let catObj =await fetch(myRequest);
```

for more information read [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)